# Criar um package a partir de outro

Tags: npm, angular

Instalei um pacote do npm, mas ele oferecia quase tudo o que eu precisava, mas, ainda sim, tive que realizar algumas customizações.
O problema é que, como trabalho com uma equipe e temos todo a questão de versionamento e a necessidade de ficar atualizando os pacotes do npm, acaba que, sempre que roda-se o `npm install`, seja para inicializar o projeto ou para atualizar os pacotes, essas customizações são sobre escritas.

Queria saber se existe alguma forma ou de não precisar fazer esse install inicial e aproveitar o pacote já com as customizações ou se seria o caso de subir um novo pacote no npm, a partir desse pacote, como um pacote customizado ou o correto seria alguma outra solução que eu não vislumbrei?

Comment: as customizações estão salvas em `--save` ou `--save-dev`? usa `gulp`?

Comment: @WMomesso, até onde eu li, o [`--save` foi descontinuado](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19578808/1606920), mas não estou usando nenhuma das opções. Quanto ao gulp, não utilizamos aqui.

Comment: O que o `npm install` está sobrescrevendo?